# Creating sub-hashes in main hash

Tags: perl, hash, copy, clone

I want to create a hash of hashes in Perl without having to explicitly write everything out. I understand that I could use `dclone` to do something like:

```
use Storable 'dclone';

my %main_hash = (
   A => {},
   B => {},
   C => {},
);

my %sub_hash = (
   a => [],
   b => [],
   c => [],
   d => [],
);

foreach my $main_key (keys %main_hash) {
   $main_hash{$main_key} = dclone {%sub_hash};
}
```

Final result:

```
%main_hash:
   A => {
     a => [],
     b => [],
     c => [],
     d => [],
   },
   B => {
     a => [],
     b => [],
     c => [],
     d => [],
   },
   C => {
     a => [],
     b => [],
     c => [],
     d => [],
   },
);
```

Is there any way to do this repeated hash insertion without relying on `dclone` or some other imported module?

Comment: You could use a loop.

Comment: Just put `my %sub_hash = ...` inside the loop, and assign it to the main hash? You hardly need dclone to clone an empty hash, do you?

Comment: I don't understand what you seek -- a builtin like `add_level` or some such?  That's much too particular to be in  a base of a language.  But, `Storable` _is_ in core, so there you go.  Or, write your own wrapper and put it together with your other utility routines...

Comment: Thanks @TLP, for some reason I didn't think of that. It worked.

Comment: Someone deleted my comment where I responded to your comment. Anyway, I added an answer, if you want to accept that answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just put the `%sub_hash` declaration inside the loop and assign it to the main hash. Each loop iteration will be a new hash, you don't need `dclone`:

```
my %main_hash = (
   A => {},
   B => {},
   C => {},
);

foreach my $main_key (keys %main_hash) {
    my %sub_hash = (
       a => [],
       b => [],
       c => [],
       d => [],
    );
   $main_hash{$main_key} = \%sub_hash;
}

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \%main_hash;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'C' => {
                   'b' => [],
                   'a' => [],
                   'c' => [],
                   'd' => []
                 },
          'B' => {
                   'b' => [],
                   'a' => [],
                   'c' => [],
                   'd' => []
                 },
          'A' => {
                   'c' => [],
                   'd' => [],
                   'b' => [],
                   'a' => []
                 }
        };
```

Answer (score 3):

Please inspect following code snippet which utilizes two indexes to generate a hash -- for compliance with your problem.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my %hash;

for my $main_key ( qw/A B C/ ) {
    for my $sub_key ( qw/a b c d/ ) {
        $hash{$main_key}{$sub_key} = [];
    }
}

say Dumper(\%hash);
```

Output

```
$VAR1 = {
          'C' => {
                   'c' => [],
                   'd' => [],
                   'a' => [],
                   'b' => []
                 },
          'B' => {
                   'b' => [],
                   'a' => [],
                   'c' => [],
                   'd' => []
                 },
          'A' => {
                   'c' => [],
                   'd' => [],
                   'b' => [],
                   'a' => []
                 }
        };
```

Comment: You don't have to use `say` with Dumper, it automatically adds newlines. Your code gives double newlines.